# Functional Derivative in Concordance function (copula theory)

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, functional-equations, functional-calculus

The concordance function (from copula theory) can be defined as follows:

$$ Q = 4 \int \int_{\mathbf{I}^2} C_2(u,v) dC_1(u,v) -1 $$

My question is regarding how to evaluate the integral, and mainly the $dC_1(u,v)$ portion.  I think this is a functional derivative, but I am unsure how to evaluate it for any given function $C_1$ (as I don't know functional analysis).  Is this equivalent to the copula density $c_1(u,v) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial u \partial v} C_1(u,v) $, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with a functional derivative.

The notation $dC(u,v)$ implies integration with respect to the so-called C-measure where the measure of a rectangle $R_{ij} =[u_{i-1},u_i]\times [v_{j-1},v_j]$ is given by

$$V_C(R_{ij}) = C(u_{i},v_{j})- C(u_{i-1},v_{j})- C(u_{i},v_{j-1})+ C(u_{i-1},v_{j-1}) .$$

If the copula is absolutely continuous then the integral reduces to

$$\int \int_{\mathbf{I}^2} C_2(u,v) \, dC_1(u,v) = \int \int_{\mathbf{I}^2} C_2(u,v) \, \frac{\partial^2C_1(u,v)}{\partial u \partial v}\,du \,dv.$$

Comment: based on this, your expression can then be additionally reduced to: $\int \int_{\mathbf{I}^2} C_2(u,v) c_1(u,v) du dv$, if I substitute the copula density, assuming $C_1$ is absolutely continuous?

Comment: @KiranK. Yes that is correct. Its similar to the case of a 1D distribution:$\int dF(x) = \int f(x)dx$ where F is the cumulative distribution function and $f(x)$ is the density function (if it exists).

Comment: Is it possible to combine the integration with respect to the C-Measure as you had described?  More specifically, is the following valid:

$\int \int_{\mathbf{I}^2} C_1(u,v) dC_1(u,v) - \int \int_{\mathbf{I}^2} C_2(u,v) dC_2(u,v) = \int \int_{\mathbf{I}^2} \left[ C_1(u,v) dC_1(u,v) - C_2(u,v) dC_2(u,v) \right] = \int \int_{\mathbf{I}^2} C_3(u,v) dC_3(u,v)$, where $C_3(u,v) = C_1(u,v)-C_2(u,v)$.  I think I am effectively applying the difference rule, which states that $(f-g)' = f'-g'$.